# jQuery Show/Hide - add / remove .active class

Tags: jquery

This has probably been asked several times, but am struggling a little. Hope someone can help. HTML & jQuery below, just want to add class '.active' to the button when div is open and remove .active when closed.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.expand').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = jQuery(this).attr("data-href");
    jQuery("#" + href).slideToggle('slow', function() {

    }).siblings('div.expanded').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <strong>Short Description</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a data-href="one" href="#" class="expand btn btn-primary btn-sm">more...</a> &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="one" style="display: none;" class="expanded row">
  <strong>Long Description</strong>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <strong>Short Description</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a data-href="two" href="#" class="expand btn btn-primary btn-sm">more...</a> &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="two" style="display: none;" class="expanded row">
  <strong>Long Description</strong>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <strong>Short Description</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a data-href="three" href="#" class="expand btn btn-primary btn-sm">more...</a> &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="three" style="display: none;" class="expanded row">
  <strong>Long Description</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use the `toggleClass()` method to successively add and remove a class on the clicked element. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery('.expand').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).data("href");
    $("#" + href).slideToggle('slow').siblings('div.expanded').hide();
    $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.expanded.row { display: none; }
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <strong>Short Description</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a data-href="one" href="#" class="expand btn btn-primary btn-sm">more...</a> &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="one" class="expanded row">
  <strong>Long Description</strong>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <strong>Short Description</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a data-href="two" href="#" class="expand btn btn-primary btn-sm">more...</a> &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="two" class="expanded row">
  <strong>Long Description</strong>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <strong>Short Description</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a data-href="three" href="#" class="expand btn btn-primary btn-sm">more...</a> &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="three" class="expanded row">
  <strong>Long Description</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Just one more thing, if I click same button again then it closes the div but keeps active class on the button.

Comment: In that case you need to exclude the current element from `removeClass()`. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much.